# How will I show image in THTMLViewer?

Tags: html, delphi

HFText is a string while HTMLViewer1 is the THTMLviewer.

```
   HFText:=  '<html><head><style>'+
                'body  {font: Arial 8pt;}'+
              '</style></head>'+
              '<body marginwidth="0">'+
              '<img src="http://10.0.0.20/picture/1.jpg" />'+
              '</body></html>';

    HTMLViewer1.LoadFromString(HFText);
```

The output of this shows an exclamation point (not the picture I want to display).
I've been told to use the OnImageRequest but I cannot find examples to show me what to do. How can I use the OnImageRequest to show the picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTMLViewer has a couple of different ways of handling images.

The simplest is to set an OnImageRequest handler and using something like the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.HTMLViewer1ImageRequest(Sender: TObject;
  const SRC: string; var Stream: TMemoryStream);
var
  wStrm : TMemoryStream;
begin
  wStrm := TMemoryStream.create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(Src, wStrm);
    Stream := wStrm;
  except
    wStrm.free;
    Stream := Nil;
  end;
end;
```

The above code assumes you already have a IdHTTP1 component on the form for getting stuff or you could also load from a TFileStream.

The value of SRC will be, in your example, "http://10.0.0.20/picture/1.jpg".

You don't free the created stream, HTMLViewer will handle that for you.  I only free the stream if there was a problem with the HTTP get.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

No answer here, but here's how I'd troubleshoot to see if you're making a basic mistake.

First, verify that when you enter this URL into your browser, you get the image.
http://10.0.0.20/picture/1.jpg
So far so good?

Next, make a file test.htm with the contents of your string.  Double-click to launch in your browser.  Still good?

Next... does it work if you use a file reference instead of http:?